# "-webkit-appearance: none;" Firefox equivalent?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there is anything equivalent to: `-webkit-appearance: none;` for Firefox?

What I want to achieve:

```
<select ...>
   <option>...</option>
   <more option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The -moz-appearance CSS property is
>   used in Gecko (Firefox) to display an
>   element using a platform-native
>   styling based on the operating
>   system's theme.

**Source:**

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to make a checkbox look like a button in chrome works like a charm but in firefox :( it doesn't. form.someform select {
   border: 1px solid #555;
   padding: 0.5em;
   font-size: 10px;
   line-height: 0.9em;
   width: 10%;
   background: #fff;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fff;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
 }

Answer (score 10):

`-moz-appearance:none` with `<select>` still shows a dropdown arrow on Firefox.

See this bug report for more information: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

Comment: The MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance imply that the `-moz-appearance: none;` is only for XUL. I certainly can't get it to work on a website.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 3):

Try this.. It works

```
select{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-overflow: '';
    text-indent: 0.1px;
}
```

Tested on Windows 8, Ubuntu and Mac, latest versions of Firefox.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangkathiriya/z3JTh/

Comment: worked great !  chrome, safari, and fox... All good... Now on to INTERNET EXPLORER

Answer (score 1):

If you want a select looking like a button in Firefox, use:

```
select { -moz-appearance: button; }
```

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/SsTHA/

Comment: and then add background-image to the button, to style it.

Comment: They've since scrapped [code]appearance[/code] from the spec so I don't doubt that Mozilla scrapped [code]-moz-appearance[/code] as well. the Mozilla resource has also updated to advise NEVER to use this value on any website.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...for me it's working on Firefox:

```css
select {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #ffffff url(../images/small-arrow-down.png) 62px 7px no-repeat;
    padding: 1px 20px 1px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;

    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer ([Internet Explorer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) and up).

Just add a small down arrow [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image for your select and it's all set.

My arrow is 30x30, but set it to your specifications.

```css
    .yourClass select{
      overflow: none;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-image: url(../images/icons/downArrow.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Fall back for Internet Explorer 10 and later  */
    .yourClass select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
```