# How to remove arrow on selectbox (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have styled my select boxes, but i can still see the arrow in my select box in firefox, i have set css so:

```
background:transparent;
content:'';
apperiance:none;
```

**Thats work on Chrome**, but on Firefox i still see default arrow, is possible to delete it also on Firefox?

Comment: -moz-appearance:none; and here is full answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748351/webkit-appearance-none-firefox-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

This should remove the arrow in selects in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE10.

```
.poa-select {
  -moz-appearance: none; 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-indent: .01px;
  text-overflow: "";
}
.poa-select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

Ideas taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351949/removing-the-ie10-select-element-arrow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083499/remove-default-select-box-arrow-in-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a cross-browser compatible route of styling form elements with CSS: it's not usually left to the designer to have control over their appearance/behaviour so form elements are notoriously difficult to style. Many browsers specifically do not allow you to style them at all!

If you need to get a consistent look across all browsers, the only route is to use JavaScript to replace the form element in-view with stylised HTML elements.

Here's an article that lists a few of the options available for you: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

The trick that works for me is to make select width more than 100% and apply overflow:hidden

```
select {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%;
}
```

[The answer from here : How to remove the arrow from a  tag in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pointer-events` property.

The idea here is to overlay an element over the native drop down arrow (to create our custom one) and then disallow pointer events on it. [see [this post](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/)]

Here is a working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9zxzz/4/)** using this method.

Also, in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/703717) I discussed this and another method in greater detail.

Comment: In the fiddle I have **replaced** the default arrow with a custom arrow - you could use the same method to remove the arrow by replacing my custom arrow with a white background (say)