# How to get use the functionality same as "-webkit-appearance" in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I wanted to remove the actual `box` in a HTML check box and have `+` and `-` marks when user clicks on it alternatively.

to remove the actual `box` in the check box I used `-webkit-appearance: none;` CSS property.
But it seems it is not working with firefox. (Working in Chrome)

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   -webkit-appearance: none; // not working in firefox , the box is still there      
}
input[type=checkbox]:after {
   content: '+';
}
input.open[type=checkbox]:after {
   content: '-';
}
```

**EDIT**

I used the `-moz-appearance: none;` also , but then it will show a shaded box , I want it to be completely gone like when it in Chrome webkit.

[The jsfiddle to the demo, when open this link in a firefox browser it will show that shadow box](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/dsrd07zx/1/)

what can be the reason for this. And how can I achieve this properly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [-webkit-appearance: none; firefox equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748351/webkit-appearance-none-firefox-equivalent)

Comment: Firefox is not a webkit browser. For Firefox you should use the prefix `-moz-`

Comment: not working Firefox 38.0.5 - http://jsfiddle.net/dsrd07zx/

Comment: I think you did not update the fiddle ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
 -webkit-appearance: none; /* webkit browsers */
   -moz-appearance:  none; /* mozilla browser */   
   -o-appearance:   none;  /* opera browsers */
    appearance:     none;    
}
```

For Browser support Refer this **[link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)**

**Edit**: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kyLq4/27/)**

If you want to completely hide the checkbox, you can try display:none instead of appearance.

```
 input[type=checkbox] {
      display:none;
  }
  input[type=checkbox] + label:after {
      content:"+";
      position:relative;
      left:0px;
      top:1px;
      z-index:100;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
      content:"-";
  }
  .checkbox_label {
      height:0px;
      width:0px;
      display:inline-block;
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      left:20px;
      z-index:100;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check' class="open" checked/>
<label for="check"></label>Check
<input type='checkbox' name='check' />
<label for="check"></label>Unchecked
```

this results same in Mozilla, Chrome.. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: already checked. but not working. Now it's showing a shadow for a box. How can I completely remove it ?

Comment: works in Chrome with no problem, open this in a firefox browser there will be a shadow box now.  :  http://jsfiddle.net/prime/dsrd07zx/1/

Comment: btw display:none wont be the same as the given functionality right ?

Comment: yeah. it's great (Y) any idea how to toggle that ? like in a real check box ? now it's static.

Comment: @prime - [Here is an example for you that will toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0kr1qs7/). The label is attached to its matching input with its `for` attribute matching the inputs `id` attribute. When you click on the label the input is checked and you have your custom toggle. The styling is all done on the label as the input is hidden.

Comment: @misterManSam yeah. that is exactly what i tried to do.. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

**-webkit-** is for Google crome and for Firefox use **-moz-**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For Firefox browser

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   -moz-appearance:  none;
   appearance:     none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **-webkit-*** prefix only works in WebKit-based browsers some of examples are: chrome, safari etc.

[Here is a list of WebKit-based desktop browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/list_of_webkitb.html)

> Mozilla Foundation is Gecko-based browser and Vendor Extension Prefix
>   for Mozilla browser is **-moz-***.

So, You have to use **-moz-appearance: none;**

Your final answer is:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the checkbox completely and want to make control over the checkbox with plus and minus sign then code given below definitely works for you:

**HTML**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="state"></span>
    <span class="text">The Check Box</span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.state:before {
    content:"+";
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .state:before {
    content:"-";
}
```

[Check code in jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dsrd07zx/6/)

Comment: already checked. but not working. Now it's showing a shadow for a box. How can I completely remove it ?

Comment: I have added code and using this you can completely remove the checkbox.

Comment: You can also check it in jsfiddle added.